# Python for-loop error `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`

Tags: python

I have a python for-loop which is supposed to use each uuid from the `uuid_list` and then go to the correct AWS S3 bucket, organisation, etc to obtain the correct certificates and keys to send messages to an IOT topic.

```
uuid_list = ["cde2107e-8736-47de-9e87-2033c3063589", "7904f39f-97b0-4a6e-bd9d-fa692c40fe6f"]

for uuid in uuid_list:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        bucket = 'sensor-certificates'
        org = "abc", "def"
        object_str = org + '/' + uuid + '/'
        result = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=object_str)
        print('-------------------')
        print(result)
        print('-------------------')
```

My issue is, I now have more than one organisation as I am scaling up. I've tried putting them in a list and like above but I'm getting the error

```
can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple: TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/iot_sim_lambda.py", line 78, in lambda_handler
    object_str = org + '/' + uuid + '/'
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Can anyone advise how I can get the loop to recognise more than one organisation when trying to obtain certificates

Comment: Looks like ```org``` or ```uuid``` is a tuple but you are concatenation ```"/"```

Comment: You have defined `org` as a tuple..... `"abc", "def"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert `org = "abc", "def"` to a list apparently and take it outside the loop.

```
uuid_list = ["cde2107e-8736-47de-9e87-2033c3063589", "7904f39f-97b0-4a6e-bd9d-fa692c40fe6f"]
orgs = ["abc", "def"]
for uuid in uuid_list:
    for org in orgs:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        bucket = 'sensor-certificates'
        object_str = org + '/' + uuid + '/'
        result = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=object_str)
        print('-------------------')
        print(result)
        print('-------------------')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following line of code will give you a tuple object:-

```
org = "abc", "def"
```

Here org is a tuple object and you are trying to concatenate it with a string. Just do the following:-

```
org = "abc" + "def"
```

it will give you a string and then you can concatenate it with **uuid**. update your code as follow:-

```
uuid_list = ["cde2107e-8736-47de-9e87-2033c3063589", "7904f39f-97b0-4a6e-bd9d-fa692c40fe6f"]

for uuid in uuid_list:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        bucket = 'sensor-certificates'
        org = "abc" + "def"
        object_str = org + '/' + uuid + '/'
        result = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=object_str)
        print('-------------------')
        print(result)
        print('-------------------')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
uuid_list = ["cde2107e-8736-47de-9e87-2033c3063589", "7904f39f-97b0-4a6e-bd9d- 
fa692c40fe6f"]

for uuid in uuid_list:
        s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
        bucket = 'sensor-certificates'
        for org in ["abc", "def"]:
            object_str = org + '/' + uuid + '/'
            result = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=object_str)
            print('-------------------')
            print(result)
            print('-------------------')
```